# Converting a lat/lon values to a small map

Tags: svg, latitude-longitude

I have a list of coordinates of lat/lon values consisting of cities around the world. I have put together a SVG map of the US which I would like to display the major cities of the world as pins on top of the SVG map. So far I've figured out that the map projection that I am displaying is a Mercator projection of the US so the next step is how can I get the X/Y coordinates for that map of the map for each city? Once I get the mercator projection from the lat/lon then how is that converted to X/Y values and then to relative X/Y values based on the size of my map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on the [Mercator projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) provides the equations you need to implement.  The Mercator projection transforms lat/long to x/y, that's what map projections do.  All you have to do once you have the x/y values is translate them into (in your case) pixels or whatever measure you use.

Comment: I understand the projection part, but how would I go about doing the translation?

Comment: My mistake, I meant the part where you said "relative X/Y values based on the size of my map?" ... how I would I relate it to the map?